# Equivalent function in Javascript from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://' + window.location.host + '/',
success: function(data){
$(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
    // will loop through 
    var images = $(this).attr("href");

    $('<p></p>').html(images).appendTo('a div of your choice')

 });
}
});
```

I couldn't find a way to do the same in javascript, I can make ajax call like this

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://' + window.location.host + '/', true);

    request.onload = function(files) {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
            // Success!

            resp = request.responseText;
        } else {
            // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

        }
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
        // There was a connection error of some sort
    };
```

but how do I get the list of the files in the directory?

CSJS and/or SSJS both answers are okay.
My main goal is not to use jQuery to accomplish what I want.

Comment: What directory are you referring to? Generally you'd use a server side language like PHP, Perl, Java, or Ruby do handle such requests.

Comment: If you have access to the server side code, a good approach would be to send JSON formatted list of files. But if the server sends HTML only, then you could use Regex to extract href attributes.

Comment: I'm guessing the server has directory listing enabled. That means the server responds with HTML listing all files/directories in the requested directory (HTTP resource). This question has nothing to do with AJAX. It's basic JavaScript DOM traversal. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dom+traversal

Comment: @Martin if you wouldn't have suggested to ` Regex to extract href attributes` i would have given your comment a vote. But using RegExp for this is a bad idea.

Comment: @KingKing The only use of `html()` in his code is `html(htmlString)`: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I fixed the target folder although it doesn't matter. I just need the way to do same in javascript.

Comment: @t.niese Yes, I know that it's generally not a good idea to use Regex everywhere, especially for XML/HTML traversal, but sometimes it's so tempting and easy - less code than setting up DocumentFragment. But I'm not sure about the performance (if it's important at all in this particular case), though.

Comment: @Barmar I misread it, however what I said about the use of `html` is still correct, see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mpHr7/). It's totally not documented.

Comment: @KingKing I think that any jQuery function that wants an htmlString will accept an element, and will simply use the element's HTML as the string.

Comment: @Barmar I think it's not the element's HTML, it's exactly the element's ***outerHTML*** (which is not able to get directly using jQuery - wrap some parent first then ...), and I'm sure that many people don't know about this, I've also just known of this, a quick note in the documentation page should be added, or maybe it's some kind of non-standard behavior (and maybe should not be used?).

Comment: @KingKing and @Barmer `.html` uses `this.empty().append( value );` at the end, [jQuery.manipulation:438](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d837f119c3729565103005d5d7fa89e1dd8110cb/src/manipulation.js#L438)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to loop through the `a:contains(.jpg)` like in your jQuery example, your best bet is probably to use a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and then call `.querySelectorAll` on it :

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = request.responseText;

// if you want to search using text
var links = div.querySelectorAll('a')
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  if (!~link.innerHTML.indexOf('.jpg'))
    continue;
  // found one !
}
// if you want to search using an attribute
var links = div.querySelectorAll("a[href*='.jpg']");
```

Comment: isn't `:contains` deprecated/removed in css3?

Comment: Your selector isn't equivalent to the original code. The original searches the text for `.jpg`, your searches the `href`. So unless the original code was wrong, this answer isn't right.

Comment: I'd be really surprised if this wasn't what was meant (but yes, it's possible). I edited my answer to add that possibility too

Comment: I am replacing div.innerHTML = data; the "data" here with "files" I guess? As its what's written in this line request.onload = function(files)

Comment: The data is `request.responseText`

Comment: @Ven Thanks, also  links.lenght should be  links.length

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the response text into a newly created `<div>` and use the standard methods to access the anchors; the following should even work for IE7:

```
// $(resp)
var doc = document.createElement('div');
doc.innerHTML = resp;

// .find('a')
var anchors = doc.getElementsByTagName('a'), // get all anchors
container = document.getElementById('some_id');

// .filter(":contains(.jpg)")
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i) {
    var contents = anchors[i].textContent || anchors[i].innerText || '';

    if (contents.indexOf('.jpg') != -1) {
        // var images = $(this).attr("href");
        // $('<p></p>').html(images).appendTo
        var para = document.createElement('p'),
        text = document.createTextNode(anchors[i].href); 

        para.appendChild(text);
        container.appendChild(para);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mehmet Yup, works on IE7 too (unlike querySelectorAll)